# Do I need to add permission for filling number in dailpad

Tags: flutter, url, permissions, launcher

Do I need to add permission for filling number in dailpad using url launcher in flutter ??? And if yes and how I can add permission in my flutter app and where...
Please help me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you specified is just warning message,i have two production app with url_launcher even if this message is showing it runs smoothly,Use like this,this is a example for integrate your with api data to ur launcher,no permission need for this.

**Import data like this**

```
import 'package:url_launcher/url_launcher.dart' as UrlLauncher;
```

**for open whatsapp**

```
UrlLauncher.launch(("https://wa.me/${"+91" + data.mobile}"));
```

**for open phone app**

```
UrlLauncher.launch(('tel://${data.mobile}'));
```

Answer (score 0):

No permission is required just use this method to launch the dialpad with the number. change the number with yours.

make sure you have imported the url launcher library.

```
url_launcher: latestVersion
```

```
onNextButtonClick() {
 launch('tel:+1 555 010 999');
}
```

Comment: Actually I am having this error so I thought the issue is with permission please clear me
 Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Note: C:\src\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\url_launcher-5.5.0\android\src\main\java\io\flutter\plugins\urllauncher\WebViewActivity.java uses or overrides a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.

Comment: i don't think this is an error. this is just a warning message. what is happening when you call the launch method?